# how to assign value in variable with a method

Tags: php, html

So I want to assign a value to $jab using

```
$jabatan->jabatannya('profile',$nama);
```

but when I echo $jab I got '1'  instead the 'value of data'.

```css
public function jabatannya($table, $nama) {
  $data=$this->_db->getAll23($table, $nama);
  if(empty($data)) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

// then refers to 
public function getAll23($table, $nama) {
  $query1="SELECT kdjurusan FROM $table WHERE username = '$nama' ";
  $result=$this->con->query($query1);
  return $result;
}
```

```html
//my codes
<form action="pebimbingan.php" method="post">
  <?php $nama = Session::get('username');
     $jab = $jabatan->jabatannya('profile',$nama);
     echo $jab;
     echo $nama;
  ?>
</form>
```

Comment: I think that means you have something. Maybe you should try to do smth like `return $result->fetchAll()`

Comment: 1 comes from the return true probably.

Comment: @pr1nc3 : Yes this is the reason

Comment: it's not working

Comment: first check `$nama = Session::get('username');` what you get here ?

Comment: I get 'kaprodi' which is the username

Comment: return `return $data;` and check with `print_r($jab);` ?

Comment: ah ... i forgot to use fetch assoc , no wonder when im using print_r it returns nothing, thx @RishiRaut

Answer (score 0):

Return `$name` not `true` here

```
public function jabatannya($table,$nama){
    $data = $this->_db->getAll23($table,$nama);
    if(empty($data)){
        return false;//if $data is empty return false, which is blank 
    }else{
        return $data;//return $data
    }
}
```

Check with `print_r($jab);` instead `echo $jab;`

Comment: did you mean return $data ? 

I tried but when i echo $jab; it said "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string "